# How to override returning type hint of inheritance class?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm able to overload a type hint of a method in subclass without its implementing. I tried something like this:

```
from typing import Any, overload


class A:
    def __init__(self, param) -> None:
        self.param = param

    def get(self) -> Any:
        return self.param


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, param) -> None:
        super().__init__(param)

    @overload
    def get(self) -> str: ... # Changed a returning type hint here


test = B('something')
test.get() # NotImplementedError: You should not call an overloaded function. A series of @overload-decorated functions outside a stub module should always be followed by an implementation that is not @overload-ed.
```

But it doesn't work.

All I want to do is just specify the types without writing any code for the method itself. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (or at least shouldn't) do this; the type of the subclass's method must be "compatible" with the type of the parent class's method. (I won't get into what, precisely, "compatible" means here.)

Your `A` class should be *generic*.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')


class A(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, param: T) -> None:
        self.param: T = param

    def get(self) -> T:
        return self.param
```

In the preceding definition, `A.get` returns a value of whatever type was used to instantiate the instance. `A(3).get` returns an `int`, `A("foo").get` returns a `str`, etc.

Then you can make `B` a subclass of `A[str]` specifically.

```
class B(A[str]):
    pass

x = B("foo")
y: str = x.get()
```

Comment: Note that if you had simply defined `class B(A):`, then `B` itself would be generic as well, instead of fixing the value of `T` for *all* instances of `B` to `str`.

Comment: While this question is XY and so your answer fits well, it's not always the case: you may be dealing with third-party base class that is not generic, but have no resources to fix it upstream. Since there is a very easy general answer to the question as asked (s/overload/if TYPE_CHECKING/), I'd suggest that your consider this alternative in your answer as well.

Comment: I think I'd sooner define a generic wrapper for the non-generic 3rd-party class. I'm not a big fan of doing one thing during type-checking and another at runtime, but I think that's certainly worth of a separate answer.

Comment: @chepner `class B(A):` would be treated as inheriting from `A[Any]`, rather than being generic. You'd need `class B(A[T]):` for `B` to be generic.

Comment: Yeah, I make that mistake occas…. freq…. all the time.

Answer (score 1):

While [answer by @chephner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78075419/14401160) is correct when you have control over the base class in question, unfortunately it is not always the case. To be clear: if you can make the base class generic, it's what you should be doing - everything below is a dirty workaround.

Now, let's say that some third-party package provides `A` defined as follows:

```py
from typing import Any

class A:
    ... # Some other stuff
    def __init__(self, param) -> None:
        self.param = param

    def get(self) -> Any:
        return self.param
```

(this is 100% equivalent to untyped package where neither the attribute nor method's return type are annotated)

It is not generic - but you want it to be. If you can contribute such change upstream (project is maintained, EOL python compatibility is out of scope, you have permission from your employer if necessary, etc.) - go on and do that, but sometimes that is not possible. In your own codebase you can define a generic wrapper like this:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Generic, TypeVar
# from some_third_party import A

_T = TypeVar("_T")

class AWrapper(Generic[_T], A):
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        # On runtime - do nothing
        def __init__(self, param: _T) -> None:
            self.param: _T = param

        def get(self) -> _T:
            return self.param
```

And now you can use `AWrapper` whenever you use `A`. You no longer interfere with its implementation: nothing in `if TYPE_CHECKING` block is executed on runtime, it's just a `False` constant to aid in complex typing.

Your `B` can now be defined as

```py
class B(AWrapper[str]): ...
```

or not defined at all, depending on your needs. Usually you'd just use `AWrapper[str]` as a type annotation directly, unless you want to really extend the class somehow.

As a cheap bonus, you'll get the following result (@chephner approach also does this, of course):

```
foo = AWrapper('foo')
reveal_type(foo.get())  # N: revealed type is "builtins.str"
```

You can try this yourself in [`mypy` playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=13ad40ddfd078e9c3c90c020cea2564a). Or [`pyright`](https://pyright-play.net/?code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoAqAmgAoCiA%2BgMIASZVA0gJIByA4gDRQCCKcXbAKYpBIJAGMuBRIIBqAQxABYAFCqKBKAF5CMhSAAUAIg1GAlKssrxAG3kBnezwBcqqO6gA6b1ADEUAGVIQSgwGAALUSh7GABXYGA3DwATQWAoCgpUJBhMg3tBG2AuBEV5CDMoAFoAPigWMBFXFQ9W6MLgT1KQcu0obvKrVtT0tEEYfI7K2p4%2BZraPEHHYkBR2oq6yiCtVWwcnbgB1HoQEUQMhETFxAG0NAF0ubjN5jyR04nJqOkZWNleFiMMlkUDk8gUiiUts4MgRpnUGk0kgtWhDOgMIDCNH0MUMUUCxhM0fDYQCUe4lnFVut0VsrHtHFAAEIGI4nM4gG4xED3F5ebxWYBgMB9NnyU7nADkQrAkosKiWADdBPIbBR4GcDDLPISDGZKn56jClSqbIJkrAZJgnEYAEaxJA2GCoeyeblGVRAA), if you prefer.